# Quickly getting rid of �

Tags: mysql, html

I'm copying html from an old website to a new one. I'm getting a bunch of issues like this:

```
City�s
```

The apostrophe is obviously wrong.

I know when, copying text from Microsoft Word, you need to strip all the garbage by pasting everything into notepad then copying the stripped version to your site. Is there a way to do this so I can quickly reformat all the pages that need to be moved?

Thanks!

Comment: What�s this question�s relation to MySQL?

Comment: Do you serve your page using UTF-8?

Comment: @animuson because of collation settings. Not sure if that has to do with it, that's why I tagged it with MySQL

Comment: Did you change the [encoding](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations) of your website? Maybe you had something like `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">` and didn't include this `<meta>` tag into your new site.

Comment: @Zeta - Thanks! I had `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf8" />` changing it to `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf8_general_ci" />` solved it. Submit an answer below and I'll accept it.

Comment: [Joel Spolsky's article on Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) is really good reading if you want to understand more of what's happening and why, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you change the [encoding](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations) of your website? Maybe you had something like `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">` and didn't include this `<meta>` tag into your new site.

There are many encoding possibilities (ISO-8859-1, UTF-8, Windows-1250 and several others...) so you have to choose the correct one for your site. General it's a good decision to use UTF-8 without BOM, since almost every browser understands UTF-8 and many text editors (e.g. Notepad++, VIM) provide a command to convert ANSI or ISO-8859-1 documents into UTF-8.

Comment: Want to add that on some Apache servers, the `AddDefaultCharset` directive in the configuration will override this meta declaration and serve pages with whatever encoding the directive specifies.